# Can I turn Windows fast start up on after I've installed Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

Can I turn windows fast start-up on when I've successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04?

I realize fast start-up will remove any changes I've made to the disk, but what if I made changes only to the portion I set aside for Ubuntu? Will fast start-up still remove changes?

Comment: More info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have fast start up turned on, provided certain conditions are adhered to:

- Fast start-up uses hybrid hibernation technology: When a system is hibernated a copy of RAM is saved; including the drive read and write caches. This saved cache ***DOES NOT*** revert changes, but rather causes file system corruption if you make changes to files that are in the cache. Thus, you can not make any changes to a disk that was mounted when the OS was hibernated; including the EFI partition.
- grub will likely refuse to mount a hibernated partition. Thus, EFI systems that share the EFI partition may refuse to boot.

Comment: The chunk of memory set aside for Ubuntu is never showed when I'm running windows. Will changes to this memory cause file corruptions?

Comment: do you mean storage not memory? drive space is not memory. Windows can not read linux partitions without third party software.

Comment: Edited and upvoted.

Comment: @fabby -- are you sure FAT is unaffected by hibernation. I have seen many say that it is; particularly in reference to rhe EFI partition.

Comment: reverted that: I've never had a problem with FAT, but not 100% sure...

Comment: So is it safe to turn fast startup on if Windows is installed in Legacy mode? I guess Linux can be installed without EFI too. Maybe I can then use the Windows Bootloader to start Linux/Ubuntu too.

Comment: @Zingam - as long as they don't share a partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to leave 'fast startup' off so you can choose between Windows and Ubuntu at start up.  Fast start up does not completely shut down windows, more like hibernation.  It should not make any changes to disk. Windows upgrade might make changes to disk you do not like.